# Fast way to match a low-resolution dataframe to higher-resolution dataframe by datetime columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, for-loop, match

I am trying to match rows in one dataframe (df1) to those in another (df2) based on a datetime column. My desired output is the df1 dataframe with matching rows from df2 added to it based on the timestamps. The datatime interval in df1 is higher resolution than that in df2. I have some code that finds the closest record in df2 whether before or after the record in df1 to do what I want, however the number of rows in each of my df1 files is high (>500,000), and I have 100 pairs of files to match. The for loop that I have is taking way too long to run. So far it has been running on the same pair of files for 24 hours! I know it works because I have taken small subsets of data and matched them quickly, and I have used this for loop a number of times on different datasets. I am wondering whether anyone would know of a quicker and more elegant way to do this, as at this rate I will never get the files merged! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Current code that is taking forever:

```
# The function that will merge the two dataframes
addSuppInfo = function(dfs1, dfs2){
  N = dim(dfs1)[1]
  MergedDF = as.data.frame(array(NA,c(N,length(names(dfs1))+length(names(dfs2)))))
  names(MergedDF) = c(names(dfs1),names(dfs2))
  suppdate = which(names(MergedDF)=="datetime")[2]  #The new, empty database has two "datetime" columns now, lets rename the second to avoid confusion
  names(MergedDF)[suppdate] = "GPS_datetime_local"

  #Convert datetimes to some universal measure of time so there can be no confusion
  dfs1$AbsTime = unclass(as.POSIXct(strptime(dfs1$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))) 
  dfs2$AbsTime = unclass(as.POSIXct(strptime(dfs2$datetime_utc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "))) 
  for(record in 1:N){
    #Find the closest record, whether before or after a time in the supp info
    NearestRow = which.min(abs(dfs2$AbsTime - dfs1$AbsTime[record]))[1] 
    if(length(NearestRow) > 0){ 
      NewRow = cbind(dfs1[record,], dfs2[NearestRow,])
      #We have two AbsTime columns which we're just using for the lookup so remove them
      NewRow = NewRow[which(names(NewRow) != "AbsTime")]  
      MergedDF[record,] = NewRow
    }else{  #if there is no matching supp data in df2, just put the df1 data in the row with a "no data" label. Bit fiddly, but neater than just leaving rows blank
      MergedDF[record,(1:(length(names(dfs1))-1))] = dfs1[record, (1:(length(names(dfs1))-1))]  #minus one because we don't want the AbsTime column we added on earlier
      MergedDF[record,length(names(dfs1)):length(names(MergedDF))] = "NA"
    }
  }
  return(MergedDF)  
}



# Create lists of the df1 and df2 filenames (for my case where I ahve lots of files in a folder).
dir = "/Users/rhiannonaustin/Desktop/Booby_analysis/EMbC/10sec_Interp_Data/Merged/Match_TDR_IMM_GPS/BB/Raw GPS match/2017/GPS_Imm/test" 
setwd(dir) 
df2files = list.files(path=dir, pattern="*_df2.csv", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
df1files = list.files(path=dir, pattern="*_df1.csv", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)


# For each file in those lists, submit them to our addSuppInfo function
# end up with df1 with new columns for the closest matching df2 row
for(i in 1:length(df2files)){
  file = df2files[i]
  #Extract the code
  df2code = strsplit(file,"_")[[1]][1]
  #Double check there is a matching df2 file
  df1code = strsplit(df1files[i],"_")[[1]][1]
  if(df2code == df1code){
    df1Data = read.csv(df1files[i], header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    df2Data = read.csv(file, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    Merged = addSuppInfo(df1Data, df2Data)
    outfile = paste(df2code,"_merged.csv",sep="")
    write.csv(Merged, file=outfile, row.names=FALSE)
  }else{
    print(paste("No matching data for ",df2code,"!!"))
  }      
}
```

Example data (obviously this small example runs quickly with my own for loop but in real life my datasets are MUCH larger!):

```
    > dput(df1Data)
    structure(list(iid = 14554:14677, datetime = c("2017-03-12 15:55:04", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:05", "2017-03-12 15:55:06", "2017-03-12 15:55:07", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:08", "2017-03-12 15:55:09", "2017-03-12 15:55:10", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:11", "2017-03-12 15:55:12", "2017-03-12 15:55:13", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:14", "2017-03-12 15:55:15", "2017-03-12 15:55:16", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:17", "2017-03-12 15:55:18", "2017-03-12 15:55:19", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:20", "2017-03-12 15:55:21", "2017-03-12 15:55:22", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:23", "2017-03-12 15:55:24", "2017-03-12 15:55:25", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:26", "2017-03-12 15:55:27", "2017-03-12 15:55:28", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:29", "2017-03-12 15:55:30", "2017-03-12 15:55:31", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:32", "2017-03-12 15:55:33", "2017-03-12 15:55:34", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:35", "2017-03-12 15:55:36", "2017-03-12 15:55:37", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:38", "2017-03-12 15:55:39", "2017-03-12 15:55:40", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:41", "2017-03-12 15:55:42", "2017-03-12 15:55:43", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:44", "2017-03-12 15:55:45", "2017-03-12 15:55:46", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:47", "2017-03-12 15:55:48", "2017-03-12 15:55:49", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:50", "2017-03-12 15:55:51", "2017-03-12 15:55:52", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:53", "2017-03-12 15:55:54", "2017-03-12 15:55:55", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:56", "2017-03-12 15:55:57", "2017-03-12 15:55:58", 
    "2017-03-12 15:55:59", "2017-03-12 15:56:00", "2017-03-12 15:56:01", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:02", "2017-03-12 15:56:03", "2017-03-12 15:56:04", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:05", "2017-03-12 15:56:06", "2017-03-12 15:56:07", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:08", "2017-03-12 15:56:09", "2017-03-12 15:56:10", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:11", "2017-03-12 15:56:12", "2017-03-12 15:56:13", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:14", "2017-03-12 15:56:15", "2017-03-12 15:56:16", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:17", "2017-03-12 15:56:18", "2017-03-12 15:56:19", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:20", "2017-03-12 15:56:21", "2017-03-12 15:56:22", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:23", "2017-03-12 15:56:24", "2017-03-12 15:56:25", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:26", "2017-03-12 15:56:27", "2017-03-12 15:56:28", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:29", "2017-03-12 15:56:30", "2017-03-12 15:56:31", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:32", "2017-03-12 15:56:33", "2017-03-12 15:56:34", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:35", "2017-03-12 15:56:36", "2017-03-12 15:56:37", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:38", "2017-03-12 15:56:39", "2017-03-12 15:56:40", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:41", "2017-03-12 15:56:42", "2017-03-12 15:56:43", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:44", "2017-03-12 15:56:45", "2017-03-12 15:56:46", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:47", "2017-03-12 15:56:48", "2017-03-12 15:56:49", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:50", "2017-03-12 15:56:51", "2017-03-12 15:56:52", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:53", "2017-03-12 15:56:54", "2017-03-12 15:56:55", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:56", "2017-03-12 15:56:57", "2017-03-12 15:56:58", 
    "2017-03-12 15:56:59", "2017-03-12 15:57:00", "2017-03-12 15:57:01", 
    "2017-03-12 15:57:02", "2017-03-12 15:57:03", "2017-03-12 15:57:04", 
    "2017-03-12 15:57:05", "2017-03-12 15:57:06", "2017-03-12 15:57:07"
    ), state = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -124L))

> dput(df2Data)
structure(list(new_id = 188889:188903, datetime_utc = c("2017-03-12 15:52:58", 
"2017-03-12 15:53:28", "2017-03-12 15:53:58", "2017-03-12 15:54:28", 
"2017-03-12 15:54:58", "2017-03-12 15:55:28", "2017-03-12 15:55:58", 
"2017-03-12 15:56:28", "2017-03-12 15:56:58", "2017-03-12 15:57:28", 
"2017-03-12 15:57:58", "2017-03-12 15:58:28", "2017-03-12 15:58:58", 
"2017-03-12 15:59:28", "2017-03-12 15:59:58"), count = c(6.138159, 
0.6693379, 5.507328, 4.041119, 1.464152, 11.73605, 12.92626, 
1.397087, 3.032117, 1.913028, 2.029836, 9.386913, 7.672296, 6.36146, 
0.5731061)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Desired output:

```
> Merged
      iid            datetime state new_id        datetime_utc     count
1   14554 2017-03-12 15:55:04     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
2   14555 2017-03-12 15:55:05     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
3   14556 2017-03-12 15:55:06     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
4   14557 2017-03-12 15:55:07     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
5   14558 2017-03-12 15:55:08     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
6   14559 2017-03-12 15:55:09     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
7   14560 2017-03-12 15:55:10     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
8   14561 2017-03-12 15:55:11     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
9   14562 2017-03-12 15:55:12     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
10  14563 2017-03-12 15:55:13     1 188893 2017-03-12 15:54:58  1.464152
11  14564 2017-03-12 15:55:14     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
12  14565 2017-03-12 15:55:15     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
13  14566 2017-03-12 15:55:16     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
14  14567 2017-03-12 15:55:17     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
15  14568 2017-03-12 15:55:18     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
16  14569 2017-03-12 15:55:19     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
17  14570 2017-03-12 15:55:20     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
18  14571 2017-03-12 15:55:21     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
19  14572 2017-03-12 15:55:22     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
20  14573 2017-03-12 15:55:23     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
21  14574 2017-03-12 15:55:24     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
22  14575 2017-03-12 15:55:25     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
23  14576 2017-03-12 15:55:26     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
24  14577 2017-03-12 15:55:27     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
25  14578 2017-03-12 15:55:28     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
26  14579 2017-03-12 15:55:29     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
27  14580 2017-03-12 15:55:30     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
28  14581 2017-03-12 15:55:31     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
29  14582 2017-03-12 15:55:32     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
30  14583 2017-03-12 15:55:33     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
31  14584 2017-03-12 15:55:34     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
32  14585 2017-03-12 15:55:35     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
33  14586 2017-03-12 15:55:36     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
34  14587 2017-03-12 15:55:37     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
35  14588 2017-03-12 15:55:38     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
36  14589 2017-03-12 15:55:39     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
37  14590 2017-03-12 15:55:40     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
38  14591 2017-03-12 15:55:41     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
39  14592 2017-03-12 15:55:42     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
40  14593 2017-03-12 15:55:43     1 188894 2017-03-12 15:55:28 11.736050
41  14594 2017-03-12 15:55:44     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
42  14595 2017-03-12 15:55:45     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
43  14596 2017-03-12 15:55:46     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
44  14597 2017-03-12 15:55:47     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
45  14598 2017-03-12 15:55:48     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
46  14599 2017-03-12 15:55:49     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
47  14600 2017-03-12 15:55:50     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
48  14601 2017-03-12 15:55:51     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
49  14602 2017-03-12 15:55:52     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
50  14603 2017-03-12 15:55:53     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
51  14604 2017-03-12 15:55:54     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
52  14605 2017-03-12 15:55:55     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
53  14606 2017-03-12 15:55:56     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
54  14607 2017-03-12 15:55:57     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
55  14608 2017-03-12 15:55:58     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
56  14609 2017-03-12 15:55:59     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
57  14610 2017-03-12 15:56:00     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
58  14611 2017-03-12 15:56:01     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
59  14612 2017-03-12 15:56:02     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
60  14613 2017-03-12 15:56:03     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
61  14614 2017-03-12 15:56:04     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
62  14615 2017-03-12 15:56:05     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
63  14616 2017-03-12 15:56:06     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
64  14617 2017-03-12 15:56:07     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
65  14618 2017-03-12 15:56:08     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
66  14619 2017-03-12 15:56:09     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
67  14620 2017-03-12 15:56:10     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
68  14621 2017-03-12 15:56:11     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
69  14622 2017-03-12 15:56:12     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
70  14623 2017-03-12 15:56:13     1 188895 2017-03-12 15:55:58 12.926260
71  14624 2017-03-12 15:56:14     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
72  14625 2017-03-12 15:56:15     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
73  14626 2017-03-12 15:56:16     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
74  14627 2017-03-12 15:56:17     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
75  14628 2017-03-12 15:56:18     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
76  14629 2017-03-12 15:56:19     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
77  14630 2017-03-12 15:56:20     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
78  14631 2017-03-12 15:56:21     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
79  14632 2017-03-12 15:56:22     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
80  14633 2017-03-12 15:56:23     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
81  14634 2017-03-12 15:56:24     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
82  14635 2017-03-12 15:56:25     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
83  14636 2017-03-12 15:56:26     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
84  14637 2017-03-12 15:56:27     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
85  14638 2017-03-12 15:56:28     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
86  14639 2017-03-12 15:56:29     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
87  14640 2017-03-12 15:56:30     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
88  14641 2017-03-12 15:56:31     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
89  14642 2017-03-12 15:56:32     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
90  14643 2017-03-12 15:56:33     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
91  14644 2017-03-12 15:56:34     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
92  14645 2017-03-12 15:56:35     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
93  14646 2017-03-12 15:56:36     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
94  14647 2017-03-12 15:56:37     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
95  14648 2017-03-12 15:56:38     1 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
96  14649 2017-03-12 15:56:39     2 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
97  14650 2017-03-12 15:56:40     2 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
98  14651 2017-03-12 15:56:41     2 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
99  14652 2017-03-12 15:56:42     2 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
100 14653 2017-03-12 15:56:43     2 188896 2017-03-12 15:56:28  1.397087
101 14654 2017-03-12 15:56:44     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
102 14655 2017-03-12 15:56:45     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
103 14656 2017-03-12 15:56:46     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
104 14657 2017-03-12 15:56:47     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
105 14658 2017-03-12 15:56:48     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
106 14659 2017-03-12 15:56:49     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
107 14660 2017-03-12 15:56:50     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
108 14661 2017-03-12 15:56:51     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
109 14662 2017-03-12 15:56:52     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
110 14663 2017-03-12 15:56:53     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
111 14664 2017-03-12 15:56:54     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
112 14665 2017-03-12 15:56:55     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
113 14666 2017-03-12 15:56:56     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
114 14667 2017-03-12 15:56:57     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
115 14668 2017-03-12 15:56:58     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
116 14669 2017-03-12 15:56:59     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
117 14670 2017-03-12 15:57:00     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
118 14671 2017-03-12 15:57:01     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
119 14672 2017-03-12 15:57:02     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
120 14673 2017-03-12 15:57:03     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
121 14674 2017-03-12 15:57:04     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
122 14675 2017-03-12 15:57:05     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
123 14676 2017-03-12 15:57:06     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
124 14677 2017-03-12 15:57:07     2 188897 2017-03-12 15:56:58  3.032117
```

Comment: You could give it a try with a left_join `dplyr::left_join(df1Data, df2Data, by = c("datetime" = "datetime_utc"))`. I also converted the timestamps to the `POSIXct` format.

Comment: @Patrick, thanks for the suggestion. I tried it buy 'left_join()' just seems to only return exact matches (i.e just adds the info from df2 for only rows with exactly matching datatimes in df1), the rest of the rows in df1 are returned with NAs, which is not what I am after. I need something that does the nearest match and returns all of the columns as in my output above, including both the datetime and datatime_utc values for the two data frames. Thanks though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a little bit around, a working code with your given data would look like this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df1Data <- df1Data %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime))

df2Data <- df2Data %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(datetime_utc = as.POSIXct(datetime_utc))

# Loop through every time entry from df1Data and find nearest time stamp in df2Data.
# Insert "new_id" from df2Data in df1Data as grouping column.
df1Data <- mutate(df1Data, df2Row = sapply(1:nrow(df1Data), function(i) 
  df2Data$new_id[which.min(abs(.data$datetime[i] - df2Data$datetime_utc))])
  )

# Merge data frames by grouping column "df2Row" from df1Data und "new_id" from df2Data
mergedData <- left_join(df1Data, df2Data, by = c("df2Row" = "new_id")) %>%
  rename("new_id" = "df2Row")
```

I dont know the performance with your big dataset, you could give it a try. If it is too slow, we could move forward with `rcpp`.

Comment: thanks so much for playing around with this. This bit of code is neat! I like it, and is SOOO much quicker. I have to go through the results with a fine toothed comb, but it looks like it has worked on my large datasets well! Thank-you!